# Unable to get the correct command parameter in a visual tree when multiple parameters are passed

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, imultivalueconverter

I am unable to pass the text of textblock tbAge as the second command parameter.
Though I am able to pass the first command parameter i.e. the text of tbName. Need to understand what extra i need to add ?.

```
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbAge" Text="{Binding DisplayAge}"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>                                                   
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="{Binding}">
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}"  MouseAction="LeftClick" >
                                <MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiCommandConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbName"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbAge" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                            </MouseBinding>
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: try `<Binding Path="DataContext.DisplayAge" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=MenuItem}"/>`

Comment: @sTrenat : Thank you so much. It's working with the change suggested by you.

Comment: @sTrenat: After I added command at ToplevelMenuItem, the command parameters in multi-binding are getting passed as DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Could you get us more details?

Comment: @sTrenat: I've posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521466/multiple-command-parameter-values-are-not-getting-passed-to-view-model-during-mu